# Fastest way to insert these dashes in python string?

Tags: python, string, string-formatting

So I know Python strings are immutable, but I have a string:

```
c['date'] = "20110104"
```

Which I would like to convert to

```
c['date'] = "2011-01-04"
```

My code:

```
c['date'] = c['date'][0:4] + "-" + c['date'][4:6] + "-" + c['date'][6:]
```

Seems a bit convoluted, no? Would it be best to save it as a separate variable and then do the same? Or would there basically be no difference?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You could use `.join()` to clean it up a little bit:

```
d = c['date']
'-'.join([d[:4], d[4:6], d[6:]])
```

Comment: If performance is what OP means by "faster", I've found that `'-'.join((d[:4],d[4:6],d[6:]))` is marginally faster (i.e. tuple instead of a list).

Comment: This looks very clean and pythonic to me :)

Comment: Simple and elegant solution!

Answer (score 10):

Dates are first class objects in Python, with a rich interface for manipulating them. The library is [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html).

```
> import datetime
> datetime.datetime.strptime('20110503','%Y%m%d').date().isoformat()
'2011-05-03'
```

Don't reinvent the wheel!

Comment: thus: `c['date'] =  pd.to_datetime(c['date'], format = '%Y%m%d')` . See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26763344/convert-pandas-column-to-datetime

Answer (score 6):

You are better off using string formatting than string concatenation

```
c['date'] = '{}-{}-{}'.format(c['date'][0:4], c['date'][4:6], c['date'][6:])
```

String concatenation is generally slower because as you said above strings are immutable.

Answer (score 4):

```
s = '20110104'


def option_1():
    return '-'.join([s[:4], s[4:6], s[6:]])

def option_1a():
    return '-'.join((s[:4], s[4:6], s[6:]))

def option_2():
    return '{}-{}-{}'.format(s[:4], s[4:6], s[6:])

def option_3():
    return '%s-%s-%s' % (s[:4], s[4:6], s[6:])

def option_original():
    return s[:4] + "-" + s[4:6] + "-" + s[6:]
```

Running `%timeit` on each yields these results

- option_1: 35.9 ns per loop
- option_1a: 35.8 ns per loop
- option_2: 36 ns per loop
- option_3: 35.8 ns per loop
- option_original: 36 ns per loop

So... pick the most readable because the performance improvements are marginal

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably do so this way, not that there's a great deal of gain:

```
d = c['date']
c['date'] = '%s-%s-%s' % (d[:4], d[4:6], d[6:])
```

The big improvement (imho) is avoiding string concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not usually the guy saying "use regex," but this is a good use-case for it:

```
import re    
c['date']=re.sub(r'.*(\w{4})(\w{2})(\w{2}).*',r"\1-\2-\3",c['date'])
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you want to convert it to a proper datetime object or rather just hard code the format, you can do the following:

```
from datetime import datetime
result = datetime.strptime(c['date'], '%Y%m%d')
print result.date().isoformat()
```

Input: '20110104'

Output: '2011-01-04'

Answer (score 1):

Add hyphen to a series of strings to datetime

```
import datetime
for i in range (0,len(c.date)):
  c.date[i] = datetime.datetime.strptime(c.date[i],'%Y%m%d').date().isoformat()
```