# Convert Pandas Column to DateTime

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, datetime

I have one field in a pandas DataFrame that was imported as string format.

It should be a datetime variable. How do I convert it to a datetime column, and then filter based on date?

Example:

```py
raw_data = pd.DataFrame({'Mycol': ['05SEP2014:00:00:00.000']})
```

Answer (score 819, accepted):

Use the [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) function, specifying a [format](http://strftime.org/) to match your data.

```
df['Mycol'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Mycol'], format='%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S.%f')
```

Comment: Note: the `format` argument isn't required. `to_datetime` is smart. Go ahead and try it without trying to match your data.

Comment: `format` is not required but passing it makes the conversion run much, much faster. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75277434/19123103) for more info.

Comment: More correctly, in the case of the OP, `format` is required, otherwise `DateParseError` occurs. `pandas` can infer some string formats, but, as point out, using `format` greatly improves performance.

Answer (score 110):

If you have more than one column to be converted you can do the following:

```
df[["col1", "col2", "col3"]] = df[["col1", "col2", "col3"]].apply(pd.to_datetime)
```

Comment: If you have different datetime formats in these columns, you can try using `format` parameter like: `apply(pd.to_datetime, format='mixed')`

Answer (score 71):

edit: recommending to use `pd.to_datetime()` instead of this because `.apply()` is generally slower.

You can use the DataFrame method [`.apply()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to operate on the values in Mycol:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(['05SEP2014:00:00:00.000'], columns=['Mycol'])
>>> df
                    Mycol
0  05SEP2014:00:00:00.000
>>> import datetime as dt
>>> df['Mycol'] = df['Mycol'].apply(lambda x: 
...     dt.datetime.strptime(x, '%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S.%f'))
>>> df
       Mycol
0 2014-09-05
```

Comment: Why use this over `pd.to_datetime`?

Comment: i probably hadn't yet seen `pd.to_datetime` when i wrote this. added a recommendation to use `pd.to_datetime`. thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 48):

Use the pandas `to_datetime` function to parse the column as DateTime. Also, by using `infer_datetime_format=True`, it will automatically detect the format and convert the mentioned column to DateTime.

```
import pandas as pd
raw_data['Mycol'] = pd.to_datetime(raw_data['Mycol'], infer_datetime_format=True)
```

Answer (score 17):

**Time Saver:**

```
raw_data['Mycol'] = pd.to_datetime(raw_data['Mycol'])
```

Comment: This doesn't work for this specific use case. It gives a `ParserError: Unknown string format: 05SEP2014:00:00:00.000`.

Answer (score 10):

###### Setting the correct `format=` is much faster than letting pandas find out<sup>1</sup>

Long story short, passing the correct `format=` from the beginning as in [chrisb's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26763793/19123103) is much faster than letting pandas figure out the format, especially if the format contains **time** component. The runtime difference for dataframes greater than 10k rows is huge (~25 times faster, so we're talking like a couple minutes vs a few seconds). All valid format options can be found at https://strftime.org/.

[image: perfplot]

###### `errors='coerce'` is useful

If some rows are not in the correct format or not datetime at all, `errors=` parameter is very useful, so that you can convert the valid rows and handle the rows that contained invalid values later.

```py
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(
    df['date'], format='%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S.%f', errors='coerce')

# for multiple columns
df[['start', 'end']] = df[['start', 'end']].apply(
    pd.to_datetime, format='%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S.%f', errors='coerce')
```

###### To silence `SettingWithCopyWarning`

On a side note, if you got this warning, then that means your dataframe was probably created by filtering another dataframe. Enable copy-on-write and you're good to go. (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76312603/19123103) for more about it).

```py
pd.set_option('copy_on_write', True)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S.%f')
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Code used to produce the timeit test plot.

```py
import perfplot
from random import choices
from datetime import datetime

mdYHMSf = range(1,13), range(1,29), range(2000,2024), range(24), *[range(60)]*2, range(1000)
perfplot.show(
    kernels=[lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x), 
             lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f'), 
             lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, infer_datetime_format=True),
             lambda s: s.apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f'))],
    labels=["pd.to_datetime(df['date'])", 
            "pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f')", 
            "pd.to_datetime(df['date'], infer_datetime_format=True)", 
            "df['date'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f'))"],
    n_range=[2**k for k in range(20)],
    setup=lambda n: pd.Series([f"{m}/{d}/{Y} {H}:{M}:{S}.{f}" 
                               for m,d,Y,H,M,S,f in zip(*[choices(e, k=n) for e in mdYHMSf])]),
    equality_check=pd.Series.equals,
    xlabel='len(df)'
)
```

---

If the column contains multiple formats, see [Convert a column of mixed format strings to a datetime Dtype](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56614558/7758804).

Comment: If I use `pd.set_option('copy_on_write', True)` I get a KeyError for the column I want to convert. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: @Lilith-Elina without looking at your specific code, I can’t say with certainty but KeyError usually occurs when there is a misspelling (“Date” vs “date”) or if the wrong axis is indexed or if there is no column with that name in the first place.

Answer (score -2):

Just like we convert object data type to float or int, use [astype()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html).

```
raw_data['Mycol'] = raw_data['Mycol'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
```

Comment: This doesn't work for this specific use case. It gives a `ParserError: Unknown string format: 05SEP2014:00:00:00.000`.