# How to convert string to datetime format in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, indexing

I have a column `I_DATE` of type string (object) in a dataframe called `train` as show below.

```
I_DATE
28-03-2012 2:15:00 PM
28-03-2012 2:17:28 PM
28-03-2012 2:50:50 PM
```

How to convert `I_DATE`  from string to datetime format & specify the format of input string.

Also, how to filter rows based on a range of dates in pandas?

Answer (score 185, accepted):

Use [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html). There is no need to specify the format in this case since the parser is able to figure it out.

```
In [51]:
pd.to_datetime(df['I_DATE'])

Out[51]:
0   2012-03-28 14:15:00
1   2012-03-28 14:17:28
2   2012-03-28 14:50:50
Name: I_DATE, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

To access the date/day/time component use the [`dt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/series.html#api-series-dt) accessor:

```
In [54]:
df['I_DATE'].dt.date

Out[54]:
0    2012-03-28
1    2012-03-28
2    2012-03-28
dtype: object

In [56]:    
df['I_DATE'].dt.time

Out[56]:
0    14:15:00
1    14:17:28
2    14:50:50
dtype: object
```

You can use strings to filter as an example:

```
In [59]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':pd.date_range(start = dt.datetime(2015,1,1), end = dt.datetime.now())})
df[(df['date'] > '2015-02-04') & (df['date'] < '2015-02-10')]

Out[59]:
         date
35 2015-02-05
36 2015-02-06
37 2015-02-07
38 2015-02-08
39 2015-02-09
```

Answer (score 22):

**Approach: 1**

Given original `string` format: `2019/03/04 00:08:48`

you can use

```
updated_df = df['timestamp'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
```

The result will be in this `datetime` format: `2019-03-04 00:08:48`

**Approach: 2**

```
updated_df = df.astype({'timestamp':'datetime64[ns]'})
```

Answer (score 6):

For a datetime in AM/PM format, the time format is `'%I:%M:%S %p'`. See all possible format combinations at https://strftime.org/. N.B. If you have time component as in the OP, the conversion will be done much, much faster if you pass the `format=` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75277434/19123103) for more info).

```py
df['I_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['I_DATE'], format='%d-%m-%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
```

To filter a datetime using a range, you can use [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range('2015-01-01', '2015-04-01')})
df.query("'2015-02-04' < date < '2015-02-10'")
```

or use [`between`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) to create a mask and filter.

```py
df[df['date'].between('2015-02-04', '2015-02-10')]
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a better approach. Sometimes, the dates can be weird in pandas, and this is my go-to solution (bulletproof).

```
df['I_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['I_DATE'], format='mixed', errors='coerce')

df[(df['I_DATE'] >= pd.to_datetime('2023-07-01')) & (df['I_DATE'] <= pd.to_datetime('2023-09-30'))]
```