# Pandas df.assign causing NaN values to appear from dates; why?

Tags: python, pandas

**Problem: `df.assign` of `Pandas` creates `NaN` values when it's not supposed to when working with dates, and I want to know why.**

I have a pandas dataframe of tweets. Here are the columns:

```
id_str            object
coordinates       object
created_at        object   ***
text              object
user              object
favorite_count     int64
retweet_count      int64
username          object
clean_text        object
```

The time of the tweet is in the column `created_at`. Even though it's an `object`, it's formatted properly, like `Mon Oct 16 23:58:55 +0000 2017`.

Now, I want to make a new column `created_date` that will only contain the month, day, year. This ended up being my solution, inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25146121/extracting-just-month-and-year-from-pandas-datetime-column-python) question and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32204631/how-to-convert-string-to-datetime-format-in-pandas-python) question.

```
df = df.assign(created_date = pd.Series([x.date() for x in pd.to_datetime(df['created_at'])]))
# Bonus question: how effective is this code in runtime or memory? If not, why?
```

The `pd.Series` constructor is there as I thought it was necessary, but I'm leaving it here in case *that* is what's causing the problems.

I later found out that 2764 out of the 29984 tweets had `NaN` values instead of the correct output (e.g. `2017-10-16` of dtype `'O'`), and I thought that the `Series` constructor was to blame, but apparently not; the problem was actually in the `df.assign`.

I used the `Counter` from `collections` for checking.

I first checked if the `Series` I created was correct.

```
# pd.Series([x.date() for x in pd.to_datetime(df['created_at'])])
Counter({datetime.date(2017, 10, 9): 8165,
        datetime.date(2017, 10, 10): 5898,
        datetime.date(2017, 10, 11): 3104,
        datetime.date(2017, 10, 12): 2067,
        datetime.date(2017, 10, 13): 1647,
        datetime.date(2017, 10, 14): 2750,
        datetime.date(2017, 10, 15): 2778,
        datetime.date(2017, 10, 16): 3575})
```

Nothing wrong there, the total number of tweets is correct, too. So, I rechecked the newly assigned column, and *there's* the problem.

```
# Counter(df['created_date'])
Counter({datetime.date(2017, 10, 16): 3240,
         datetime.date(2017, 10, 15): 2413,
         datetime.date(2017, 10, 14): 2431,
         datetime.date(2017, 10, 13): 1369,
         datetime.date(2017, 10, 12): 1680,
         datetime.date(2017, 10, 11): 2736,
         datetime.date(2017, 10, 10): 5409,
         datetime.date(2017, 10, 9): 7942,
         nan: 2764})
```

I've fixed the problem by removing the `pd.Series` constructor, but now I want to know **why** this is happening, since I can't find anything similar. I apologize in advance if the only problem is that I wasn't thinking hard enough.

Comment: That date format is insane. Did you explicitly specify the format or let it get inferred? I wouldn't be surprised if some ambiguity in the format created the problem.

Comment: Also, I suspect you know this, but calling Series on a list comprehension over a series is not efficient. Use the `.dt` attribute to access the series datetime functions if necessary (though you can fix this particular problem earlier in the pipeline).