# How can I convert string to datetime?

Tags: python

How can I convert string column  to datetime in pandas?

My columns is as follows

```
Date

01Jan2019
01Feb2019
01Mar2019
```

How can I convert this to a pandas date time?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Pandas Column to DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26763344/convert-pandas-column-to-datetime)

Comment: duplicated? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting string into datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime)

Comment: What’s the problem? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. See: [tour], [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert string to datetime format in pandas python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32204631/how-to-convert-string-to-datetime-format-in-pandas-python)

Answer (score 1):

The following code will convert your String column to datetime64

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], infer_datetime_format=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try with below code

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime_object =datetime.strptime('01Jan2019', '%d%b%Y')
```

Comment: The question is about Pandas, no?