# Changing date string to pandas datestamp

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with column `date` which looks like this:

```
Feb 24, 2020 @ 12:47:31.616
```

I would like it to become this:

```
2020-02-24
```

I can achieve this using slicing since I am dealing only with one week's data hence all months will be Feb.

Is there a neat pandas way to change the datestamp to date format I desire?

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: How are you reading the data? You can specify a datetime format at read time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert string to datetime format in pandas python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32204631/how-to-convert-string-to-datetime-format-in-pandas-python)

Comment: @Nabin - Only partial dupe, so no dupe

Answer (score 0):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with format `%b %d, %Y @ %H:%M:%S.%f` and then if necessary convert to dates by [`Series.dt.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.date.html) or to datetimes by [`Series.dt.floor`](http://pandaspydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html):

```
#dates
df = pd.DataFrame({'dates':['Feb 24, 2020 @ 12:47:31.616','Feb 24, 2020 @ 12:47:31.616']})
df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dates'], format='%b %d, %Y @ %H:%M:%S.%f').dt.date
#datetimes
df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dates'], format='%b %d, %Y @ %H:%M:%S.%f').dt.floor('d')
print (df)
        dates
0  2020-02-24
1  2020-02-24
```

Comment: I would mark this question as duplicate rather than answering with one line, Mr. 471K

Comment: @Nabin - What dupe? Can you add link ?

Answer (score 0):

Using `pd.to_datetime` with `Series.str.split`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['Feb 24, 2020 @ 12:47:31.616']})

                          date
0  Feb 24, 2020 @ 12:47:31.616
```

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'].str.split('\s@\s').str[0], format='%b %d, %Y')

        date
0 2020-02-24
```

Comment: Because somebody with 20.3K shouldn't be answering these kinds of questions.

Comment: Can you clarify why? If it's a duplicate, link me the duplicate question and I will be happily to mark it as one, but I don't think this is a dupe.

Comment: @Erfan - Agree.