# Pandas: Change column of integers to datetime and add a timestamp

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with an id column, and a date column made up of an integer.

```
d = {'id': [1, 2], 'date': [20161031, 20170930]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

   id      date
0   1  20161031
1   2  20170930
```

I can convert the date column to an actual date like so.

```
df['date'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(str(x), format='%Y%m%d'))

   id       date
0   1 2016-10-31
1   2 2017-09-30
```

But I need to have this field as a timestamp with with hours, minutes, and seconds so that it is compatible with my database table. I don't care what the the values are, we can keep it easy by setting it to zeros.

```
2016-10-31 00:00:00
2017-09-30 00:00:00
```

What is the best way to change this field to a timestamp? I tried

```
df['date'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(str(x), format='%Y%m%d%H%M%S'))
```

but pandas didn't like that.

I think I could append six 0's to the end of every value in that field and then use the above statement, but I was wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: use `pandas.to_datetime(df['date']) ` that is enough, already discussed at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32204631/how-to-convert-string-to-datetime-format-in-pandas-python

Comment: format : string, default None
strftime to parse time, eg “%d/%m/%Y”, note that “%f” will parse all the way up to nanoseconds.

Comment: @Serge are you sure it works in this case though? E.g. `pd.to_datetime(20161031) == pd.Timestamp('1970-01-01 00:00:00.020161031')`

Comment: You are right, it should be converted to string with `df['date'].apply(str)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With pandas it is simpler and faster to convert entire columns. First you convert to string and then to time stamp

```
pandas.to_datatime(df['date'].apply(str))
```

PS there are few other conversion methods of varying performance https://datatofish.com/fastest-way-to-convert-integers-to-strings-in-pandas-dataframe/

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be that [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) doesn't accept dates in this integer format:

`pd.to_datetime(20161031)` gives `Timestamp('1970-01-01 00:00:00.020161031')`

It assumes the integers are nanoseconds since 1970-01-01.

You have to convert to a string first:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"].astype(str))
```

Output:

```
   id       date
0   1 2016-10-31
1   2 2017-09-30
```

Note that these are datetimes so they include a time component (which are all zero in this case) even though they are not shown in the data frame representation above.

```
print(df.loc[0,'date'])
```

Out:

```
Timestamp('2016-10-31 00:00:00')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"].dt.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S'))
```