# How to convert dataframe string into date time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, time-series

```
df['Year,date']
 Sep 10 
1       Sep 16 
2       Aug 01 
3       Sep 30 
4       Sep 28 
         ...   
2230    Jul 20 
2231    Oct 26 
2232    Oct 13 
2233    Dec 31 
2234    Jul 08 
Name: Year,date, Length: 2235, dtype: object
```

This is my dataframe and I want to convert each row into data time
in Months and date, format, I have tried some codes but not working on mine.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert string to datetime format in pandas python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32204631/how-to-convert-string-to-datetime-format-in-pandas-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome to Stack Overflow. To convert the dataframe you mentioned from string to date time, you can use below code.
**Initial data**

```
from datetime import datetime
data = {'date': ['Sep 16', 'Aug 01', 'Sep 30', 'Sep 16']}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
df.info()
>>  #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype 
   ---  ------  --------------  ----- 
    0   date    4 non-null      object

print(df)
>>     date
   0  Sep 16
   1  Aug 01
   2  Sep 30
   3  Sep 16
```

To convert to datetime....

```
pd.to_datetime(df['date'],format='%b %d').dt.to_period('M')
df.info()
>> #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype         
   ---  ------  --------------  -----         
   0   date    4 non-null      datetime64[ns]
   dtypes: datetime64[ns](1)
print(df)
>>         date
     0 1900-09-16
     1 1900-08-01
     2 1900-09-30
     3 1900-09-16
```

You might have noticed that the year is taken as 1900 as this is the default. So, in case you need it as this year, you would do this...

```
from datetime import datetime
data = {'date': ['Sep 16', 'Aug 01', 'Sep 30', 'Sep 16']}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
df.date = datetime.now().strftime("%Y") + " " + df.date
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date, format='%Y %b %d')
print(df)
>>    date
   0 2022-09-16
   1 2022-08-01
   2 2022-09-30
   3 2022-09-16
```

Now that the date is stored in the dataframe in as a datetime format, if you want to see this information in the `mon dd` format, you would need to do this...

```
print(df.date.dt.strftime("%b %d"))
>> 0    Sep 16
   1    Aug 01
   2    Sep 30
   3    Sep 16
```

Note that the date in `df` is still in datetime format.