# How to populate a dataframe using Date, Month and Year and manipulate that dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-science, google-colaboratory

I want to create a new table using pandas or python which will have the same columns as the picture but I want to add all the dates between two dates of the actual table in the new table.
For example in the picture in 1st row, Effect Date is 13 februray,2022 and Price is 220 and in 2nd row Effect Date is 23 September, 2021. 
I want in the new table there will be all the dates between 13 februray,2022 and 23 September, 2021. all other column value will same except the MRP/Unit.
Between 2/13/2022 and 8/23/2021 all values in MRP/Unit will be 220. Between 9/23/2021 and 9/9/2019 all values in MRP/Unit will be 210.

[image]

Comment: There are several separate things you are trying to do there, each of which is its own question.  There are lots of online resources to learn how to construct a pandas dataframe, as well as the other things you are asking.   If you look at these, and still get stumped on specific steps you can ask those on SO, but you should do some research on your own first.

Answer (score 1):

*Here, I skipped the part that you should convert date strings to date objects. you can check that you in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32204631/how-to-convert-string-to-datetime-format-in-pandas-python)*

Think of your dataframe as `initial_df`:

```py
initial_df = pd.DataFrame({'Weight':[215.235,215.235,215.235,215.235],
              'Effect Date':[date(2022,2,13),date(2021,9,23),date(2019,10,9),date(2019,7,14)],
              'MRP/Unit(Tk)':[220,210,200,190]})
```

```
    Weight Effect Date  MRP/Unit(Tk)
0  215.235  2022-02-13           220
1  215.235  2021-09-23           210
2  215.235  2019-10-09           200
3  215.235  2019-07-14           190
```

first you should extract the first and last date in your `Effect Date` column.

```py
start_date = initial_df['Effect Date'].min()
end_date = initial_df['Effect Date'].max()
```

Now you can create a *date range* in pandas using the [`pd.date_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) method.

```py
date_index = pd.date_range(start_date,end_date)
```

second, you can create a new dataframe with this daterange as index and [left join](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) it with your `initial_df` to get other rows. since the first dataframe only has an index column, the other should set the join key (`Effect Date`) as it's index.

```py
result_df = pd.DataFrame(index=date_index)\
  .join(initial_df.set_index('Effect Date'),
        how='left')
```

```
             Weight  MRP/Unit(Tk)
2019-07-14  215.235         190.0
2019-07-15      NaN           NaN
2019-07-16      NaN           NaN
2019-07-17      NaN           NaN
2019-07-18      NaN           NaN
...             ...           ...
2022-02-09      NaN           NaN
2022-02-10      NaN           NaN
2022-02-11      NaN           NaN
2022-02-12      NaN           NaN
2022-02-13  215.235         220.0
```

Now we can fill the `NaN` values in other columns using the *backfill* or *forwardfill* strategy of pandas's [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) method. This method can be done on single columns too.

```py
result_df.fillna(method='bfill')
```

```
             Weight  MRP/Unit(Tk)
2019-07-14  215.235         190.0
2019-07-15  215.235         200.0
2019-07-16  215.235         200.0
2019-07-17  215.235         200.0
2019-07-18  215.235         200.0
...             ...           ...
2022-02-09  215.235         220.0
2022-02-10  215.235         220.0
2022-02-11  215.235         220.0
2022-02-12  215.235         220.0
2022-02-13  215.235         220.0
```

If you want `MRP/Unit(Tk)` values to vary one month before some date, you should use backward fill values to populate another column. Make a copy of the `Effect Date` column in your `initial_df`. Then apply backward fill to that column in the `result_df` too. Then you can decide which value you want in the result dataframe, knowing the next date after this date and the following *MRP/Unit* value in `initial_df`.

Answer (score 0):

- You can use `.shift(-1)` method to get the date in the next row.
- apply `pd.date_range` to create list of date between the current date and the next date in each row
- use `.explode()`

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': ['09/25/2021','09/27/2021','09/30/2021'],
    'value': [1,2,3]
})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['next_date'] =  df['date'].shift(-1)
df['next_date'] = df['next_date'].fillna(df['date'])
df['list_of_date_between'] = df.apply(lambda row: pd.date_range(row['date'], row['next_date'], freq='D').tolist()[:-1], axis=1)
df = df.explode('list_of_date_between')
df['list_of_date_between'] = df['list_of_date_between'].fillna(df['date'])
df = df[['list_of_date_between', 'value']]
df = df.rename({'list_of_date_between': 'date'}, axis=1)
print (df.to_markdown(index=False))
```

Output

| date | value |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-09-25 00:00:00 | 1 |
| 2021-09-26 00:00:00 | 1 |
| 2021-09-27 00:00:00 | 2 |
| 2021-09-28 00:00:00 | 2 |
| 2021-09-29 00:00:00 | 2 |
| 2021-09-30 00:00:00 | 3 |