# Converting column of floats to datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a column of my dataframe that is made up of the following:

`df['Year] = [2025, 2024, NaN, 2023, 2026, NaN]` (these are type `float64`)

How can I convert these years to something in datetime format? Since there are no months or days included I feel like they have to output as `[01-01-2025, 01-01-2021, NaT, 01-01-2023, 01-01-2026, NaT]` by default.

But if there was a way to still have the column as `[2025, 2024, NaT, 2023, 2026, NaT]` then that would work well too.

Using `df['Year'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Year']).year` just output `[1970, 1970, NaN, 1970, 1970, NaN]`.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert string to datetime format in pandas python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32204631/how-to-convert-string-to-datetime-format-in-pandas-python)

Comment: The problem is that my column of float does not include anything for DD or MM. It is just a column of years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pandas' `to_datetime()` and set `errors='coerce'` to take care of the NaNs (-> NaT)

```
df['Year'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Year'], format='%Y', errors='coerce')
```

The output is going to be like `01-01-2025, 01-01-2021 ...`

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most elegant solution but if you convert the column to string and fill the empty with a dummy year (say 1900) you can use parser from dateutil

```
from dateutil import parser

('01/01/'+df['year']).fillna('1900').apply(parser.parse)
```

Out[67]:

```
0   2025-01-01
1   2024-01-01
2   1900-07-21
3   2023-01-01
4   2026-01-01
5   1900-07-21
```

Comment: It seems to work, but ideally we want the NaN to stay as NaN or NaT.

Comment: Hi, could you please format your code better? [This article may be helpful to you.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) It will improve the readability of your answer!