# Convert date-like string to date format in python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe with a column called `date`, formatted as string and it looks like this:

```
date
20200109
20200304
20210112
```

Is there a way I can format that into datetime?

Comment: Duplicate of [How to convert string to datetime format in pandas python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32204631/how-to-convert-string-to-datetime-format-in-pandas-python)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `pd.to_datetime` with custom `format=`:

```py
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"], format="%Y%d%m")  # use "%Y%m%d" if month is first
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
        date
0 2020-09-01
1 2020-04-03
2 2021-12-01
```

---

<sup>**Note:** [datetime format *cheatsheet*](https://strftime.org/)</sup>

Comment: Are you sure it's `%Y%d%m` and not `%Y%m%d`?

Comment: @gre_gor That I'm not sure. But hopefully OP knows the correct order and changes the `format=` string accordingly.

Comment: It is Y%m%d, but I sorted that out! TY