# Pandas- Difference of two column using column position

Tags: pandas

I have a Dataframe where I would like to find the difference between two columns, however would like to use the column position instead of the column name when I am trying to find the difference.

Sample Dataframe:

```
id, purchase_date, cost, service_date
101, 01-01-2022, 101, 04-01-2022
102, 01-05-2022, 101, 03-21-2022
```

I would like to find the difference between purchase_date and service_date, however trying to use the column position instead of column name

I tried something like this but it failed:

```
df.iloc[:,1] - df.iloc[:,3]
```

Expect to add one more new column that would give difference in days between these two columns.

Comment: Hey @BigBen, I did use that to select columns but not able to perform any actions like finding the difference

Comment: @BigBen My bad, I am selecting the respective columns as `df.iloc[:,1]` and `df.iloc[:,3]`.. However I am not able to find the difference. May be I am missing something here

Comment: and why are you unable? What is the problem? Maybe use pd.to_datetime, if your columns are strings

Comment: Hey @VladimirFokow I tried something like this `df.iloc[:,3] - df.iloc[:,1]` but that returned `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'`

Comment: Then you need to convert to datetime, and your question has nothing to do with selecting columns by position.

Comment: See [How to convert string to datetime format in pandas python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32204631/14627505)

Comment: Oops that dint strike me, thanks for guiding me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all, what's you date format?
this solution assumes the following format %m-%d-%Y

```
    df['difference'] = pd.to_datetime(df['purchase_date']) - pd.to_datetime(df['service_date'])
```

you can also add what ever format you have like

```
    pd.to_datetime(date, format='%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
```