# Convert index to DateTime

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, indexing

I have an excel file with data. I defined this file as a DataFrame (5000,12) using python/pandas. As an index, I set the date based on the below:

```
Data_Final=Data.set_index(['Date Time']) # Data_Final is Dataframe
```

For example, the first index is 01/01/2016 00:00. Now I want this index in datetime. How is this conversion done?

Answer (score 0):

use the .to_datetime() method

```
Data_Final = Data
Data_Final['Date Time'] = pd.to_datetime(Data['Date Time'])
Data_Final.set_index('Date Time', inplace=True)
```

[How to convert string to datetime format in pandas python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32204631/how-to-convert-string-to-datetime-format-in-pandas-python)

Comment: Not working. Maybe because the Date Time column is an index and it can not read it as a datetime.

Comment: this answer suggests reassigning initial `Data` to `Data_Final` to change the `Date Time` column dtype and then set the index again. You may avoid such conflicts changing the index directly `Data_Final.index = pd.to_datetime(Data_Final.index)`