# Convert Pandas Column to DateTime II

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I am trying to convert a column of DateTime Strings into a Pandas-comprehensible Datetime Format. Of course I already googled and tried several solutions.
[Convert Pandas Column to DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26763344/convert-pandas-column-to-datetime?rq=1)

This one appeared the most encouraging for me but both recommended ways did not work for my dataset.
The details: 
Dataset name: co,

Column: index-column,

Format: 15.07.2015 24:00 with no more blancs before or after.

My efforts:

```
co['newdate'] = pd.to_datetime(co.index, format='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M')
```

The next one I tried after I transformed the Index-col to a "normal" column named "Datum"

```
co['newdate'] = co['Datum'].apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.strptime(x,'%d.%m.%Y %H:%M'))
```

The error: time data '15.07.2015 24:00' does not match format '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M'

this error occurs in both solutions. Anyone an idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your format string is correct but your data is not, `24` is not a valid hour component hence the error:

```
In [138]:

pd.to_datetime('15.07.2015 24:00', format = '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.5\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\tseries\tools.py in _convert_listlike(arg, box, format)
    329             try:
--> 330                 values, tz = tslib.datetime_to_datetime64(arg)
    331                 return DatetimeIndex._simple_new(values, None, tz=tz)

pandas\tslib.pyx in pandas.tslib.datetime_to_datetime64 (pandas\tslib.c:23823)()

TypeError: Unrecognized value type: <class 'str'>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-138-1546fb6950f0> in <module>()
----> 1 pd.to_datetime('15.07.2015 24:00', format = '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M')

C:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.5\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\tseries\tools.py in to_datetime(arg, errors, dayfirst, utc, box, format, exact, coerce, unit, infer_datetime_format)
    343         return _convert_listlike(arg, box, format)
    344 
--> 345     return _convert_listlike(np.array([ arg ]), box, format)[0]
    346 
    347 class DateParseError(ValueError):

C:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.5\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\tseries\tools.py in _convert_listlike(arg, box, format)
    331                 return DatetimeIndex._simple_new(values, None, tz=tz)
    332             except (ValueError, TypeError):
--> 333                 raise e
    334 
    335     if arg is None:

C:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.5\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\tseries\tools.py in _convert_listlike(arg, box, format)
    305                     try:
    306                         result = tslib.array_strptime(
--> 307                             arg, format, exact=exact, coerce=coerce
    308                         )
    309                     except (tslib.OutOfBoundsDatetime):

pandas\tslib.pyx in pandas.tslib.array_strptime (pandas\tslib.c:39900)()

ValueError: time data '15.07.2015 24:00' does not match format '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M' (match)
```

whilst `23:59` will parse fine

```
In [139]:
pd.to_datetime('15.07.2015 23:59', format = '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M')

Out[139]:
Timestamp('2015-07-15 23:59:00')
```

You need to replace `24` with `0` in order for this to parse:

```
In [140]:
pd.to_datetime('15.07.2015 00:00', format = '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M')

Out[140]:
Timestamp('2015-07-15 00:00:00')
```

So what you can do is call the vectorised [`str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html#pandas.Series.str.replace) to fix these errant hour values:

```
In [144]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['15.07.2015 24:00']})
print(df)
df['date'] = df['date'].str.replace('24:','00:')
print(df)
pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format = '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M')

               date
0  15.07.2015 24:00
               date
0  15.07.2015 00:00
Out[144]:
0   2015-07-15
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

So in your case you can do:

```
co.index = co.index.str.replace('24:','00:')
```

and then convert as before

Comment: wow that is amazingly elegant. however it is not perfectly correct as 15.07.2015 24:00 is actually 16.07.2015 00:00 - means midnight of the next day

Comment: I'd convert to `00:00` or `23:59` and then add a day/minute to those rows