# Can't convert a Python List to timeSeries

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I tried to resolve this problem for more than a day. I have this type of list:

```
TempList[:5]
[(datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 25, 7, 29, 28, 337000),), (datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 8, 7, 44, 55, 53000),), (datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 10, 5, 44, 51, 867000),), (datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 10, 1, 42, 15, 740000),), (datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 2, 1, 7, 09, 687000),)]
```

I would like to converti it as a Pandas [Time Series](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#time-series-date-functionality).
I found this useful [function: pd.to_datetime](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#converting-to-timestamps). But when I try
to convert it:

```
Dates = pd.to_datetime(TempList)
```

I got This Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/util/decorators.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/tseries/tools.py", line 291, in to_datetime
    unit=unit, infer_datetime_format=infer_datetime_format)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/tseries/tools.py", line 427, in _to_datetime
    return _convert_listlike(arg, box, format)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/tseries/tools.py", line 341, in _convert_listlike
    raise TypeError('arg must be a string, datetime, list, tuple, '
TypeError: arg must be a string, datetime, list, tuple, 1-d array, or Series
```

But TempList is a list! I can't understand how to resolve this. How can I convert my list?
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a list of tuples. Try converting that into a plain list, and then using `pd.to_datetime`.
Something like (I do not have python right now)

```
tl2 = [ ti[0] for ti in TempList ]
Dates = pd.to_datetime(tl2)
```

PS1: What else do you have in `TempList`? (you only show the first 5 elements).

PS2: You might need to use the `format` argument, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/26763793/2707864.

Comment: I've only shown the first five elements because TempList is very long (about 24000 elements).. they're all datetime.datetime. I'm about to try your solution!