# Pandas : TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, data-science

I have a dataframe that contains

```
user_id    date       browser  conversion  test  sex  age  country
   1    2015-12-03       IE        1         0    M   32.0   US
```

Here is my code:

```py
from sklearn import tree
data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data.date)
columns = [c for c in data.columns.tolist() if c not in ["test"]]
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(data[columns], data["test"])
```

I am getting this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-560-95a8a54aa939> in <module>()
      4 from sklearn import tree
      5 clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=2, min_samples_leaf = (len(data)/100) )
----> 6 clf = clf.fit(data[columns],data["test"])

C:\Users\SnehaPriya\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\tree.pyc in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, check_input, X_idx_sorted)
    152         random_state = check_random_state(self.random_state)
    153         if check_input:
--> 154             X = check_array(X, dtype=DTYPE, accept_sparse="csc")
    155             if issparse(X):
    156                 X.sort_indices()

C:\Users\SnehaPriya\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.pyc in check_array(array, accept_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    371                                       force_all_finite)
    372     else:
--> 373         array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)
    374 
    375         if ensure_2d:

TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number
```

How do I overcome this error?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

IIUC you need exclude column `date` also:

```
columns = [c for c in columns if c not in ["test", 'date']]
```

because error:

> TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Timestamp'

Answer (score 11):

A solution which keeps the date(time) column:

```
data['date'] = pd.to_numeric(pd.to_datetime(data['date']))
```

Answer (score 1):

###### Ideas to preserve datetime as features in the model

Assuming the dates are relevant only with respect to how much time has passed since the observation, a solution to keep the datetime column as a feature in the model is to convert it into time difference between now and the datetimes.

```py
data['date'] = (pd.Timestamp('now') - pd.to_datetime(data['date'])).dt.total_seconds()
```

Or you can convert the datetimes into integers straight up.

```py
data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date']).astype('int64')
```

---

N.B. To convert strings to datetime, passing `format=` makes the conversion run much, much faster (25 times faster). See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75277434/19123103) for the benchmark and see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75304878/19123103) for ideas to pass the format if your datetime column doesn't have a uniform format.