# OneHotEncoding Error:TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Timestamp'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I want to cluster user.
I got TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Timestamp'.
df is FataFrame like

```
id     | date                  | country       | code
1        2015-10-16T12:00:30     Japan            A
3        2017-08-20T15:50:44     America          B
4        2016-22-56T11:32:01     China            E
```

csv is

```
1,2015-10-16T12:00:30,Japan,A
3,2017-08-20T15:50:44,America,B
4,2016-22-56T11:32:01,China,E
```

I wrote code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame(df)

df = df.values.tolist()
enc = OneHotEncoder()
enc.fit(df)
```

I wrote code to do OneHotEncoding

```
enc = OneHotEncoder()
enc.fit(df)
```

I cannot understand how to fix this.

Comment: This is probably unrelated, but what does this line do? `df = pd.DataFrame(df)`

Comment: @user1558604 It transform csv into DataFrame

Comment: The line above that does that.  `pd.read_csv` returns a df.

Comment: I remove df = pd.DataFrame(df) ,but nothing is changed

Comment: Duplicate question - there's some good info here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53896757/float-argument-must-be-a-string-or-a-number-not-timestamp?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Yo are trying to apply One-Hot Encoding to complete dataframe, which also includes a feature column with datatype TimeStamp, i.e. Date in your DF. One-Hot encoding can only be done either on a string value or a number value, representing a category among many, converting this single column into multi-dimensional array representing each class as a column, with a cell having 1 if that row belongs to that particular class.

Notice, this is not possible in datatype TimeStamp, as date/time datatypes do not represent any form of classes. So, instead change encoder fitting line to only include Country and Code columns.

```
enc_vals = enc.fit_transform(df[['country', 'code']].values)
```

This should give you a 2D array.

Also, as @user1558604 has already mentioned in comment, there is no need to mention this line:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

As your CSV file is automatically read into a DataFrame by Pandas by:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
```

Thanks