# TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Timestamp'

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science

I have a bunch of data that I am reading from a CSV file like this into Pandas with a 
`df = pd.read_csv('C:\\User\\desktop\\master.csv', parse_dates=[['Date', 'Time']])`

```
Date     Time        kW
3/1/2011 12:15:00 AM 171.36
3/1/2011 12:30:00 AM 181.44
3/1/2011 12:45:00 AM 175.68
3/1/2011 1:00:00 AM 180.00
3/1/2011 1:15:00 AM 175.68
```

doing a `df.head()` print:

```
            Date_Time    kW
0 2011-03-01 00:15:00 171.36
1 2011-03-01 00:30:00 181.44
2 2011-03-01 00:45:00 175.68
3 2011-03-01 01:00:00 180.00
```

And my machine learning experiment I am attempting to add in some additional columns based on the time stamp day of week, hour, minute.

```
df['month'] = df.Date_Time.dt.month
df['Day_of_week'] = df.Date_Time.dt.dayofweek
df['hour'] = df.Date_Time.dt.hour
df['minute'] = df.Date_Time.dt.minute
```

Without really knowing what I am doing, my code for sci kit learn is below where I am attempting to follow [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41256626/pandas-typeerror-float-argument-must-be-a-string-or-a-number) with the same Type Error.

```
columns = df.columns.tolist()
columns = [c for c in columns if c not in ['kW', 'date']]
from sklearn import tree
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=2, min_samples_leaf = (len(df)/100) )
clf = clf.fit(df[columns],df['kW'])
```

Generates the same error as the SO post above but the solution isn't fixing my issue:
`float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Timestamp'`

***EDIT***

If I print a `df.dtypes`:

```
Date_Time      datetime64[ns]
kW                    float64
month                   int64
Day_of_week             int64
hour                    int64
minute                  int64
dtype: object
```

If I print a `df.columns`:
`Index(['Date_Time', 'kW', 'month', 'Day_of_week', 'hour', 'minute'], dtype='object')`

Comment: `[c for c in columns if c not in ['kW', 'date']]` should  be `[c for c in columns if c not in ['kW', 'Date']]` with `'date'` capitalized `'Date'`.  Otherwise, you didn't actually eliminate it from the list `columns`

Comment: Am I doing anything wrong? With a `columns = [c for c in columns if c not in ['kW', 'Date']]` and `clf = clf.fit(df[columns],df['kW'])` I still get the same error..

Comment: Looks like you have 3 columns to start `['Date', 'Time', 'kW']` but you refer to a column `'Date_Time'`  I'm unclear what is actually in your dataframe.  Either way, you have a `Timestamp` column that isn't getting filtered out.  You are attempting to filter your dataframe with the variable name `columns` but aren't being very careful about what it contains nor what `df` contains.  One way to address this would be to use `df.select_dtypes(include=np.number)` to get all numeric columns.  So you can just do `clf.fit(df.select_dtypes(include=np.number), df['kW'])`

Comment: Can you print df.columns and update the post? Not sure if you have columns Date, Time or Date_Time

Comment: Hi @Vaishali, printing `df.columns` gives me `Index(['Date_Time', 'kW', 'month', 'Day_of_week', 'hour', 'minute'], dtype='object')`... Is my entire issue I am not setting Date_Time as the pd index?

Comment: The list comprehension you used assumes that there is a column by name date. Since your column name is Date_Time, you need [c for c in columns if c not in ['kW', 'Date_Time']]

Comment: I updated the post to include `df.columns` if it makes any difference..

Comment: Use  [c for c in columns if c not in ['kW', 'Date_Time']]

Comment: That worked @Vaishali... If you post an answer Ill hit the green box

Comment: It was just a typo due to incorrect column name, I think you can delete the question

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to replace this line

```
columns = [c for c in columns if c not in ['kW', 'date']]
```

with this

```
columns = [c for c in columns if c not in ['kW', 'Date_Time']]
```

Your code should look like this:

```
columns = df.columns.tolist()
columns = [c for c in columns if c not in ['kW', 'Date_Time']]
from sklearn import tree
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=2, min_samples_leaf = (len(df)/100) )
clf = clf.fit(df[columns],df['kW'])
```

We cannot use string columns in sciKit-learn. SciKit-learn accept only numerical data types.
You can check your coluns dtypes using `df.dtypes` attribute.

If some of your columns are 'object' or 'datetime', add them to ['kW', 'Date_Time'] list.

Comment: Check this post now.