# Convert a column of mixed format strings to a datetime Dtype

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

When converting a pandas dataframe column from `object` to `datetime` using `astype` function, the behavior is different depending on if the strings have the time component or not. What is the correct way of converting the column?

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['12/07/2013 21:50:00','13/07/2013 00:30:00','15/07/2013','11/07/2013']})

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S", exact=False, dayfirst=True, errors='ignore')
```

Output:

```
                   Date
0   12/07/2013 21:50:00
1   13/07/2013 00:30:00
2   15/07/2013
3   11/07/2013
```

but the dtype is still `object`. When doing:

```py
df['Date'] = df['Date'].astype('datetime64')
```

it becomes of `datetime` dtype but the day and month are not parsed correctly on rows 0 and 3.

```
                   Date
0   2013-12-07 21:50:00
1   2013-07-13 00:30:00
2   2013-07-15 00:00:00
3   2013-11-07 00:00:00
```

The expected result is:

```
                   Date
0   2013-07-12 21:50:00
1   2013-07-13 00:30:00
2   2013-07-15 00:00:00
3   2013-07-11 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 3):

If we look at the [source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/0b04174115d156541552da07e2c220df613ae36f/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py#L445-L449), if you pass `format=` and `dayfirst=` arguments, `dayfirst=` will never be read because passing `format=` calls a C function (np_datetime_strings.c) that doesn't use `dayfirst=` to make conversions. On the other hand, if you pass only `dayfirst=`, it will be used to first guess the format and falls back on `dateutil.parser.parse` to make conversions. So, use only one of them.

In most cases,

```py
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

does the job.

In the specific example in the OP, passing `dayfirst=True` does the job.

```py
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True)
```

That said, passing the `format=` makes the conversion run ~25x faster (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75277434/19123103) for more info), so if your frame is anything larger than 10k rows, then it's better to pass the `format=`. Now since the format is mixed, one way is to perform the conversion in two steps (`errors='coerce'` argument will be useful)

- convert the datetimes with time component
- fill in the NaT values (the "coerced" rows) by a Series converted with a different format.

```py
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S', errors='coerce')
df['Date'] = df['Date'].fillna(pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d/%m/%Y', errors='coerce'))
```

This method (of performing or more conversions) can be used to convert any column with "weirdly" formatted datetimes.

---

Since pandas 2.0, `format=` accepts `'mixed'`, i.e. `pd.to_datetime(dates, format='mixed')` but this is pretty error-prone, so it's probably better to use `dayfirst=True` or two-step `format=` (as done above) instead.