# Converting string to datetime object in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a column called 'SubmitTime' which is a string per observation. An example would be:  'Wed Apr 12 14:42:23 PDT 2017'

I need to sort this dataframe based on submission time (the ones that submitted first, are on top). How can I convert this column into datetime and sort the dataframe in Pandas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Pandas Column to DateTime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26763344/convert-pandas-column-to-datetime)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you dataframe is `df`

```
df.iloc[pd.to_datetime(df.SubmitTime).argsort()]
```

This leaves your dataframe intact, `'SubmitTime'` remains strings

Otherwise, I'd convert `'SubmitTime'` to datetime and sort

```
df.assign(SubmitTime=pd.to_datetime(df.SubmitTime)).sort_values('SubmitTime')
```