# Plotting a time series?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, datetime, time-series

I have a data set which has dates in the first column, and a "result" integer which is either 1 or 0. The date column was successfully converted to a time object. I tried to plot the values directly using matplotlib's plot function, but that did not work..
Sample:

```
    Date       Result
2017-01-06     0.0
2017-01-06     1.0
2017-01-06     0.0
2017-01-07     0.0
2017-01-07     0.0
```

I tried using `df.plot()`, but the resulting plot has very undesirable results.

What I want at the end of the day is dates on the x axis, and the "result" on the y axis. Where am I going wrong? What's wrong with what I'm doing?

[image: Here's the graph]

Comment: You should, please, show us your code. Otherwise, how can we know what you might be doing incorrectly?

Comment: well what I did was just use this newly created df and simply used df.plot(),

Resulting graph has no dates i X axis, only a range 0 -> 2000

Comment: The fact that you have something called `df` suggests the use of pandas. Then, in addition to that, you have only two distinct dates. I'm wondering what kind of plot you expect to get, and also exactly what you did.

Comment: I did use pandas, and the dataframe is a simple 2 column df, Date column and result column, with values of either 0 or 1. I wanna plot the values by time, for every timestamp.

Comment: try `df.set_index('Date').plot()` or `df.plot(x='Date', y='Result')`. I guess it's because of the plot use index of `df` as x-axis. So for your `df`, it defaults 0->2000. So set the 'Date' columns as index and try again

Comment: Is that **exactly** what the dataframe looks like? Did you format your date column as a date?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Please use

`df.set_index('Date').plot()`

or

`df.plot(x='Date', y='Result')`

because of the plot by default use index of `df` as the x-axis, so you should set the 'Date' column as the index, or specify which column to use as the x-axis.

see more at [pandas.DataFrame.plot](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html)

Comment: Bless you.  I've been working on this problem forever and this is the first answer I've seen that cuts to the heart of the issue.  Now that I know that matplotlib was plotting the index on the x axis, it makes perfect sense.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

One common issue is that `Date` column looks like `datetime64` but is actually `object`. So changing the dtype fixes that issue. N.B. Passing the datetime `format=` makes the conversion run much, much faster (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75277434/19123103) for more info).

```py
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
df.plot(x='Date', y='Result', kind='scatter', rot=90)
```