# How to plot timeseries graph with pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

```
0          1
0 2019-08-06   1.264652
1 2019-08-10   4.136145
2 2019-08-15  18.981240
3 2019-08-20  15.608667
4 2019-09-07   4.108212
```

I have a pandas dataframe like this and I want to plot a time series graph based on this how can I do that.

This is what I am doing.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(DATA_LIST)
    print(df.head())
    df.plot()
    plt.show()
```

but I need the date values in X axis.

Comment: Does this answer your Question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43707620/plotting-a-time-series

Answer (score 0):

```
 df.plot(x="name of the column with dates", y="name of the column with dates")
```