# converting datetime for entire column

Tags: python, datetime

***[Still unanswered]***

Hello I recently identified a solution to convert a time format into hours and minutes.

```
from datetime import datetime

x = datetime.strptime('2017-01-01T19:33:28+0000', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')\ .strftime('%H:%M')
```

However I can only do this for one value in a column. How do you apply it to all values in an entire column?

Here are the column values I want to convert: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUHIj.png)

**Edit 1:** [Here is my failed attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEJF3.png) The error says "TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Series"

**Edit 2:** Here is [my 2nd attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gRnY.png) This error says `SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character`

and also `NameError: name 'pandas' is not defined`
(even though I'm using pandas which is confusing?)

Thanks!

Comment: An entire column in what?

Comment: @Pallison, So how do you select your column of data? Are you using `pandas`?

Comment: Yes I have a jupyter notebook and I'm using pandas. I can select a column of data by writing df.first_event_date

Answer (score 0):

It's always better work with pandas when you work with data.

When you convert your data into a dataframe_pandas (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) , you can just:

```
import pandas as pd

df --> dataframe

df['column']=pd.to_datetime(df['column'], format=...)
```

This post can help you [Convert Pandas Column to DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26763344/convert-pandas-column-to-datetime)

Comment: Thanks -- the other problem is that I want to separate hours and minutes

Comment: Can anyone else help? Thanks

Comment: Hi, @Pallison, did you "import pandas"? because  "NameError: name 'pandas' is not defined" means that you didn't imported

Comment: Try with "import pandas as pd" and df['column']=pd.to_datetime(df['column'], format=...). I forgot that