# Date converted to <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'> instead of datetime.datetime

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas 'Time' column which has values in the format `4/7/2013` of type string.
I am trying to convert the entire column into datetime.datetime format.
I used the following code-

```
df3['Date'] =  pd.to_datetime(df3['Date'],format='%m/%d/%Y')
```

but after doing `print(type(df3['Date'].iloc[0]))` the type is coming `<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>` but I wanted to convert it to datetime.datetime format.

What am I doing wrong?

I used this as reference-[Convert Pandas Column to DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26763344/convert-pandas-column-to-datetime)

Comment: Nothing, this is pandas datetime drype. Is there some particular reason you don't want to use it?

Comment: I am doing subtraction in a loop with a data type datetime.datetime

Comment: Are you trying to extract the date part? `pd.to_datetime(df3['Date'],format='%m/%d/%Y').dt.date`

Comment: @user2285236 my column only has date like 4/7/2013 of type string

Comment: Why are you doing subtraction in a loop? If you are going to do that, just use a list (or perhaps a map iterator) instead of a Dataframe. Pandas data structures are meant to be used with vectorised operations on primitive data types, not Python for loops with Python objects. This is the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why don't you tell us what you are *really* trying to accomplish

Answer (score 2):

You can apply:

```
 YOUR_TARGET.to_pydatetime()
```

EXP:

```
 In [1]: type(pd.date_range('2018-01', '2020-05', freq='M')[0])
 Out[1]: pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp


 In [62]: type(pd.date_range('2018-01', '2020-05', freq='M')[0].to_pydatetime())
 Out[62]: datetime.datetime
```

I think that is what you need right?

Answer (score 0):

From the [Pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

> Return type depends on input:
>
> list-like: DatetimeIndex
>
> Series: Series of datetime64 dtype
>
> scalar: Timestamp

So, `to_timestamp` returns a Pandas-style datetime object. There's really no benefit to converting to a `datetime.datetimr` object, but if you feel inclined to do so, you can convert the Pandas-style datetime object to a string, then use `datetime.strptime` to turn that string into a `datetime.datetime` object.

Comment: I already have a column which has dates in the string format...I want to convert the  rows in column to datetime.datetime