# Pandas convert YEARMODA in to a datetime. convert to datetimelike values

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
       YEARMODA  TEMP   MAX   MIN
0      19730701  74.5  90.0  53.6
1      19730702  74.5  88.9  57.9
2      19730703  81.7  95.0  63.0
3      19730704  85.0  95.0  65.8
4      19730705  85.0  97.9  63.9
```

How do I get the date to datetimelike. I want to get the average and standard deviation of the temp by year and by month. I know how to use group, it's just working with YEARMODA that is the problem

Comment: sorry what exactly is the problem? you want to convert `YEARMODA` in to a datetime?

Comment: yes. I want to convert YEARMODA in to a datetime

Comment: Have you looked at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26763344/convert-pandas-column-to-datetime and you can get the formatting strings at https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Comment: Yes, I have tried that and I kept getting "ValueError: time data 19730701 does not match format '%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S.%f' (match)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two ways to solve this, take your pick

```
df['YEARMODA'] = pd.to_datetime(df['YEARMODA'], format='%Y%m%d')

    YEARMODA  TEMP   MAX   MIN
0 1973-07-01  74.5  90.0  53.6
1 1973-07-02  74.5  88.9  57.9
2 1973-07-03  81.7  95.0  63.0
3 1973-07-04  85.0  95.0  65.8
4 1973-07-05  85.0  97.9  63.9

--------------------------------------------------------------------

from functools import partial

p = partial(pd.to_datetime, format='%Y%m%d')

df['YEARMODA'] = df['YEARMODA'].apply(p)

    YEARMODA  TEMP   MAX   MIN
0 1973-07-01  74.5  90.0  53.6
1 1973-07-02  74.5  88.9  57.9
2 1973-07-03  81.7  95.0  63.0
3 1973-07-04  85.0  95.0  65.8
4 1973-07-05  85.0  97.9  63.9
```

Edit: The issue you are having is you are not providing the correct `format` to your `pd.to_datetime` expression hence it is failing.

Edit 2: To get the `std` by month according to how you want to do it you would do it as such.

```
df.groupby(df.YEARMODA.apply(p).dt.strftime('%B')).TEMP.std()


YEARMODA
July    5.321936
Name: TEMP, dtype: float64


df.assign(temp=pd.to_datetime(df['YEARMODA'], format='%Y%m%d') \
  .dt \
  .strftime('%B')) \
  .groupby('temp') \
  .TEMP \
  .std()

temp
July    5.321936
Name: TEMP, dtype: float64
```

Comment: How do I sort this monthStd = data.groupby(data['Date'].dt.strftime('%B'))['TEMP'].std() by month of the year not by alphabetical order

Comment: April        9.018825
August       5.630849
December     8.293874
February     8.593250
January      8.221079
July         5.530319
June         9.193297
March        8.056263
May          9.363602
November     8.559405
October      8.234723
September    8.065359

Comment: It is in alphabetical order. I want it to be in date order. like January , February , March , April , March

Comment: that's for you to figure out since that is outside the scope of this question. I answered the question you asked here in completeness.