# Data Frame column to extract time with AM/PM fromat from datetime value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am reading in some excel data that contains datetime values stored as '8/13/2019  4:51:00 AM' and formatted as '4:51:00 AM' in excel.  I would like to have a data frame that converts the value to a timestamp formatted as '4:51 AM' or H%:M% p%.

I have tried using datetime strptime but I don't believe I have been using it correctly.  None of my attempts have worked so I have left it out of the code below.  The two columns I would like to convert are 'In Punch' and 'Out Punch'

```
import pandas as pd
import pymssql
import numpy as np
import xlrd
import os
from datetime import datetime as dt    

rpt = xlrd.open_workbook('OpenReport.xls', logfile=open(os.devnull,'w'))
rpt = pd.read_excel(rpt, skiprows=7)[['ID','Employee','Date/Time','In Punch','Out Punch',
                                      'In Punch Comment','Out Punch Comment', 'Totaled Amount']]
rpt
```

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.  Thanks

EDIT:
Working with the following modifications now.

```
rpt['In Punch'] = pd.to_datetime(rpt['In Punch']).dt.strftime('%I:%M %p')
rpt['Out Punch'] = pd.to_datetime(rpt['Out Punch']).dt.strftime('%I:%M %p')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try working with `datetime` inside pandas. [Convert Pandas Column to DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26763344/convert-pandas-column-to-datetime) has some good suggestions that could help you out.

```
rpt['In Punch'] = pd.to_datetime(rpt['In Punch'])
```

Then you can do all sorts of lovely tweaks to a datetime. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html

Comment: Thanks for the reference, seems to working after a few modifications.