# pd.to_datetime Minitue and Hour

Tags: pandas, datetimepicker

this is my code I did not put hour and seconds in my data but the result I got includes time, do you know if it is possible to remove the time?

input

```
fitness['Date']=pd.to_datetime(fitness['Date'])
```

result

> 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000000   1979-09-09
>
> 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000001   1979-09-09
>
> 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000002   1979-09-09
>
> 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000003   1979-09-09
>
> 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000004   1979-09-09

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26763344/convert-pandas-column-to-datetime#26763793

Answer (score 0):

As discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067704/how-to-change-the-datetime-format-in-pandas), the `dt.strftime` function can be utilised to format the output.

```py
fitness['Date_formatted'] = pd.to_datetime(fitness['Date']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

This will format the output of `to_datetime()` to follow `%Y-%m-%d`. However, the dtype of the column will be converted to `string`. You can find documentation for the function [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html).