# How to extract a string dataframe column to date?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe with a column which contains strings of the form yyyymmdd.

I would like to create a new column with this date format: yyyy-mm-dd

I tried severals operations as:
df['Timestamp'] = df['stringdate'].apply(lambda x:datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d'))
but it does't work: all my data are 1970-01-01

Perhaps use pd.str.extract of pd.str.split but i'm lost.

Thanks a lot
Thierry

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Pandas Column to DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26763344/convert-pandas-column-to-datetime)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the format key I suspect. It states the format in which the string is, not in which you want it to be in the end. You should use

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y%m%d')
```

If you want to have it as a new string in the format `yyy-mm-dd` you then have to apply `strftime`:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y%m%d').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: I got error: time data '19810501' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d' . I think i have to extract 4 first characters for year, 2 characters for month ...etc ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method `pd.to_datetime(Series)`: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html

Here is an example:

```
test = pd.DataFrame(['20200114', '20191223'])
pd.to_datetime(test[0])
```

Outputs:

```
0   2020-01-14
1   2019-12-23
Name: 0, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Thanks but can you give me the exact instruction please with a panda dataframe and apply function? Somethinks like                                                                     df['Timestamp'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d'))                                                                                                                  Thanks a lot