# Changing epoch time to readable time and plotting in python/pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, epoch

I have stock data in a .csv file. The date column is in unix time. 
How do I convert the entire column to readable dates? Also, how do I set the x axis to day-times and not seconds? Very new to this..

RBZ one day.csv looks like this:
[RBZ csv data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9sA6i.png)

```
df = pd.read_csv('RBZ one day.csv')
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,7))
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((40,40), (0,0), rowspan=40, colspan=40)

ax1.plot(open)
```

Comment: The convertion to unix time is discussed in this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26763344/convert-pandas-column-to-datetime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your datetime column is in Unix time to the millisecond, so use this to convert it:

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'],unit='ms')
```

Then you can plot using `ax.plot_date()`:

```
ax1.plot_date(df['datetime'],df['open'])
```

Example:

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

df = pd.DataFrame({'datetime':[1575293880000,1575294180000,1575294420000,1575297000000,1575297060000],
                   'open':[np.random.random() for i in range(5)]})
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
ax = fig.gca()
ax.plot_date(df['datetime'],df['open'])
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.HourLocator())
fig.autofmt_xdate()
```

Results in:

[image]