# Convert dataframe to datetime comma separated?

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime

I am reading one file having 2 columns.

```
1 : issue
2 is timestamp
```

`timestamp column : 2020, 1, 15, 2, 32, 40, 113000`

How to convert to Datetime format?

Comment: can you show how your dataframe and csv looks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Pandas Column to DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26763344/convert-pandas-column-to-datetime)

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you wrote I think you want

```
pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], format='%Y,%m,%d,%H,%M,%S')
0   2020-01-15 02:32:40
Name: timestamp, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 0):

This question seem to already have an answer here:

[Convert Pandas Column to DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26763344/convert-pandas-column-to-datetime)

You can pass any string format to pd.to_datetime, so in your case you would use commas.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"label": ["label1", "label2"], 
                   "dt":["2020, 1, 15, 2, 32, 40, 113000", 
                         "2020, 1, 16, 2, 32, 40, 113000"]
                  })
df['dt_2'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['dt'], format='%Y, %m, %d, %H, %M, %S, %f')
df.head()
```

Which will yield

```
    label   dt                              dt_2
0   label1  2020, 1, 15, 2, 32, 40, 113000  2020-01-15 02:32:40.113
1   label2  2020, 1, 16, 2, 32, 40, 113000  2020-01-16 02:32:40.113
```