# Apply timestamp convert to date to multiple columns in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I want to convert two timestamp columns `start_date` and `end_date` to normal date columns:

```
   id     start_date       end_date
0   1  1578448800000  1583632800000
1   2  1582164000000  1582250400000
2   3  1582509600000  1582596000000
3   4  1583373600000  1588557600000
4   5  1582509600000  1582596000000
5   6  1582164000000  1582250400000
6   7  1581040800000  1586224800000
7   8  1582423200000  1582509600000
8   9  1583287200000  1583373600000
```

The following code works for one timestamp, but how could I apply it to those two columns? 
Thanks for your kind helps.

```
import datetime
timestamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1500000000)
print(timestamp.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

Output:

```
2017-07-14 10:40:00
```

I also try with `pd.to_datetime(df['start_date']/1000).apply(lambda x: x.date())` which give a incorrect result.

```
0    1970-01-01
1    1970-01-01
2    1970-01-01
3    1970-01-01
4    1970-01-01
5    1970-01-01
6    1970-01-01
7    1970-01-01
8    1970-01-01
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Pandas Column to DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26763344/convert-pandas-column-to-datetime)

Comment: Thanks, I just tried, the solutions in this post doesn't work for my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with list of columns names and [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with parameter `unit='ms'`:

```
cols = ['start_date', 'end_date']
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(pd.to_datetime, unit='ms')
print (df)
   id          start_date            end_date
0   1 2020-01-08 02:00:00 2020-03-08 02:00:00
1   2 2020-02-20 02:00:00 2020-02-21 02:00:00
2   3 2020-02-24 02:00:00 2020-02-25 02:00:00
3   4 2020-03-05 02:00:00 2020-05-04 02:00:00
4   5 2020-02-24 02:00:00 2020-02-25 02:00:00
5   6 2020-02-20 02:00:00 2020-02-21 02:00:00
6   7 2020-02-07 02:00:00 2020-04-07 02:00:00
7   8 2020-02-23 02:00:00 2020-02-24 02:00:00
8   9 2020-03-04 02:00:00 2020-03-05 02:00:00
```

EDIT: For dates add lambda function with [`Series.dt.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.date.html):

```
cols = ['start_date', 'end_date']
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, unit='ms').dt.date)
print (df)
   id  start_date    end_date
0   1  2020-01-08  2020-03-08
1   2  2020-02-20  2020-02-21
2   3  2020-02-24  2020-02-25
3   4  2020-03-05  2020-05-04
4   5  2020-02-24  2020-02-25
5   6  2020-02-20  2020-02-21
6   7  2020-02-07  2020-04-07
7   8  2020-02-23  2020-02-24
8   9  2020-03-04  2020-03-05
```

Or convert each column separately:

```
df['start_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_date'], unit='ms')
df['end_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end_date'], unit='ms')
print (df)
   id          start_date            end_date
0   1 2020-01-08 02:00:00 2020-03-08 02:00:00
1   2 2020-02-20 02:00:00 2020-02-21 02:00:00
2   3 2020-02-24 02:00:00 2020-02-25 02:00:00
3   4 2020-03-05 02:00:00 2020-05-04 02:00:00
4   5 2020-02-24 02:00:00 2020-02-25 02:00:00
5   6 2020-02-20 02:00:00 2020-02-21 02:00:00
6   7 2020-02-07 02:00:00 2020-04-07 02:00:00
7   8 2020-02-23 02:00:00 2020-02-24 02:00:00
8   9 2020-03-04 02:00:00 2020-03-05 02:00:00
```

And for dates:

```
df['start_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_date'], unit='ms').dt.date
df['end_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end_date'], unit='ms').dt.date
```

Comment: Thank you, and how to take `Y-m-d` only and igore `H-m-s`? I add `dt.date`, it doesn't work.

Comment: @ahbon - do you need dates or datetimes with no times?

Comment: Only date is OK for me.