# Chanding a dataframe values from int type to date

Tags: python, pandas, datetimeindex

I have the following dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'date': [1988, 1988, 2000, 2005],
'value': [2100, 4568, 7896, 68909]
})
```

I want to make a time series based on this df. How can i change the year from int to a datetimeindex so i can plot a timeseries?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Pandas Column to DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26763344/convert-pandas-column-to-datetime)

Comment: to convert to datetime: `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'],format = '%Y')`. to plot `df.set_index('date')['value'].plot()`

Comment: perfect worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use: [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) to convert to datetime. [`DataFrame.set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) in order to get and plot the `Series`. You can plot it with [`Series.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.plot.html)

```
(df.assign(date = pd.to_datetime(df['date'],format = '%Y'))
   .set_index('date')['value']
   .plot())
```

---

If you want keep the series use:

```
s = (df.assign(date = pd.to_datetime(df['date'],format = '%Y'))
       .set_index('date')['value'])
```

and then:

```
s.plot()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'date': [1988, 1988, 2000, 2005],
'value': [2100, 4568, 7896, 68909]
}) 

date = []
for year in  df.date:
    date.append(pd.datetime(year,1,1))
df.index=date
df['value'].plot()
```

[image]

Comment: for loop here is innecesary https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html accept `Series` like arg