# Why don't they match? Python, created_at to date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In my dataframe, I have columns like: `"created_at" ,"date","time"`;

they are something like  : `"1558522813000", "2019-05-22","21:00:13"`

I tried :

```
df['created_at'] = pd.to_datetime(df.created_at)
```

but it generated something like `"1970-01-01 00:25:54.068778"`, which I know it's wrong because it doesn't match the "date" and "time" in the same row (it should be `"2019-05-22...."`)

How is this possible?

Comment: Google how to use datetime.strftime to get datetime from string

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Pandas Column to DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26763344/convert-pandas-column-to-datetime)

Comment: `1558522813000` is an epoch time in ms, but pandas assumes ns by default - try passing `unit='ms'` and see if that works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `df['created_at'] = pd.to_datetime(df.created_at, unit="ms").dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")` will fix your problem.

Here is a complete example:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> from datetime import datetime

>>> df = pd.DataFrame([{"created_at": 1558522813000}])
      created_at
0  1558522813000

>>> df['created_at'] = pd.to_datetime(df.created_at, unit="ms").dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
>>> print(df)
   created_at
0  2019-05-22
```

Comment: I tried : df['created_at'] = pd.to_datetime(df.created_at, unit="ms").dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

this does improved to show the actual year but still doesn't match the date in some rows, any idea why this happens? Thank you

Comment: For example, created_at:"1554068778000",date:"2019-04-01",time:"07:46:18"

and after I run the code: created_at : "2019-03-31"

Comment: This could happen for multiple reasons. It could be due to human error especially when the difference isn't that big. Are there any examples where the **expected date** didn't match the **actual date**?

Comment: @ElenaWang 1554068778000 is definitely 2019-03-31 23:46:18 - seems exactly 8h off compared to your date and time, so I suppose it is a timezone problem, ie. your "date" and "time" are in local timezone while "created_at" is in UTC.

Comment: You might try adding 8h = 28800000 ms to all your `created_at` times and see if it fixed the "doesn't match" problem.

Answer (score -1):

Check this example:
`pd.to_datetime(1490195805433502912, unit='ns')`

source: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html

You have to set the unit. For the other dates, you can slice them up and provide year, month, etc. to the to_datetime funcion.

Hope this helps.