# Converting Data to Date Type When Writing with Openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, datetime, openpyxl

Question about formatting data when writing to an Excel doc as I am a bit newer to using Openpyxl.

I have an excel sheet that I am writing data to where one of the columns is a column that holds the current date in 'mm/dd/yyyy' format. Currently when writing to the Excel doc, my code reformats the date to 'yyyy-mm-dd' format, and the excel doc does not recognize the data as 'Date' type, but as 'General' data type.

Here is my Python code to write the date to the sheet.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from date time import date

workbookName = "Excel workbook.xlsm"
wb = Workbook()
wb = load_workbook(workbookName, data_only=True, keep_vba=True)
ws = wb["Sheet1"]
rowCount = 2000 
insertRow = rowCount + 7

origDate = date.today()
dateString = datetime.datetime.strftime(origDate, '%m/%d/%Y')
insertDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(dateString, '%m/%d/%Y').date()
dateCell = ws.cell(row = insertRow, column = 1)
dateCell.value = insertDate

wb.save("Excel workbook.xlsm")
```

So for example, if I ran this code using today's date of `03/19/2021`, the cell would look like `2021-03-18` with `General` type.

Not sure what I am missing, but I want the inserted cell to have 'Date' type in 'mm/dd/yyyy' format. Any pointers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this can be done simply with:

```
dateCell.value = origDate
dateCell.number_format = 'mm/dd/yyyy'
```

Note that there's no such thing as a date data type in Excel. A date is just a formatted number. "Date" (and "General" for that matter) are just formatting; the underlying value of the cell is separate and unchanged.

Though if you really want the cell to show as having a "Date" format and not "Custom", perhaps:

```
dateCell.number_format = 'mm/dd/yyyy;@'
```

Comment: That works for formatting, but the data type of the cell is listed as Custom when I want it to be Date. Do you know how I could format the writing so the type is Date?

Comment: @NathanAnderson - I don't see why that's necessary but see the edit. There's no such thing as a Date data type. There's just date formatting. A date is a number.