# String to datetime in pandas reversed

Tags: pandas, string, datetime

I am dealing with time objects saved as strings in the form 57:44.6 (second, minute, hour).I am trying to convert the column elements to datetime using pd_todatetime. There results are Nat. How can i change the format of the string to HH:MM:SS (6:44:57)before converting?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Pandas Column to DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26763344/convert-pandas-column-to-datetime)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

provide the appropriate format specifier '%S:%M.%H'. Ex:

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(['57:44.6'])

dts = pd.to_datetime(s, format='%S:%M.%H')
# dts
# 0   1900-01-01 06:44:57
# dtype: datetime64[ns]
```