# How to convert Str into Date time format in python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a data frame of type str which I want to convert into DateTime format and then want to create another column for time only in hour: min :sec

```
   TimeStamp
  20200706 07:00:00
  20200706 08:07:00
  20200706 08:28:00
  20200706 09:30:00
  20200706 09:31:00
  20200706 09:32:00
```

Comment: Additionally to Nicolos answer: in general you can use the standard libraries `datetime` and `time`. in datetime you would use `strftime()` and `strptime()` to read and write specific formats https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes. `time` doesn't offer as much options, but sometimes it's faster to use.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Pandas Column to DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26763344/convert-pandas-column-to-datetime)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to have it as timestamp

```
import pandas as pd
pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'])
```

To have another (string) column with hour, minutes and seconds

```
pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp']).dt.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
```