# How to deal with date (type: object) in Python (Data analytics)

Tags: python, datetime

My dataset has a date column that I need to do some calculations with. One typical cell would look like "3/21/2020" and I checked with dtypes, they are all objects. I want to know the difference between two dates, what should I do with the dates? What should I convert them to? And how can I do the calculation? I am not so familiar with datetime package. I hope this description is clear. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should probably convert them to date. `df['object_column'] = pd.to_datetime(df['object_column], errors='coerce')` You can also add a default value if the cells contain wonky data. DT fields can be rough.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Pandas Column to DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26763344/convert-pandas-column-to-datetime)

Comment: That worked thank you!