# How to format ''date+hour'' string into date time format

Tags: python, pandas

i have a column hour which has  value like  '2019091300',"2019091301" the  last two digits are hour value i want to transform it '2019-091-13 00:00:00', '2019-09-13 01:00:00' etc. '20190913'  could be transformable by DateTime  formatting . but I am stuck processing the last hour part . any  solution would be helpful

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Pandas Column to DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26763344/convert-pandas-column-to-datetime)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add parameter format with `%Y` for `YYYY`, `%m` for `MM`, `%d` for `DD` and `%H` for `HH` in [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y%m%d%H')
```