# convert integer to date in python

Tags: python, pandas, date-formatting

I have one field that has Interger format and I want that to be converted as date format (YYYYMM).
entries are
201801 it should appear as 201801 but as date format ( original one is Int 64 format) because I want to plot it on a chart. If I use as Chart is not coming in proper way.

Comment: PS: I am working on Pandas in python

Comment: Please post some sample data with expected output.

Comment: So you want to convert it to a timestamp?

Comment: 202002                                                                                                                                                       202001                    output should also be same only format should be date format, currently it is int64

Comment: i don't want time stamp as I don't want time portion I want only YYYYMM format to be read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can represent dates with the `.dt` method of the Series

Adapted from my similar answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/66038817/4541045

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"dates": [200101, 200202, 202010]})
#     dates
# 0  200101
# 1  200202
# 2  202010
df.dates = pd.to_datetime(df.dates, format="%Y%m")  # make a datetime
#        dates
# 0 2001-01-01
# 1 2002-02-01
# 2 2020-10-01
df.dates.dt.strftime("%Y%m")  # represent datetime Series
# 0    200101
# 1    200202
# 2    202010
# Name: dates, dtype: object
```

NOTE `df.dates` is just referring to the column named `dates` in this case

Comment: I don't want time or day part, I just want YYYYMM

Comment: @Ashish - one can easily change the format of the chart tick labels, which seems like your actual end goal.

Comment: Indeed - just change the args to the equivalent of `Series.dt.strftime()`! (probably `%Y%m`)

Comment: no it did not work, it shows syntax error. I tried following                                                                     '''dt2['ReportFiscalMonth']= dt2['ReportFiscalMonth'].dt.strftime(%Y%m)'''

Comment: @ti7 it worked thanks a lot                                                                                                                                     '''dt2['ReportFiscalMonth'] = pd.to_datetime(dt2['ReportFiscalMonth'], format="%Y%m")'''

Comment: Any time / splendid!