# Converting datetime to string python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a pandas dataframe that has a datetime column called "time". From this column, I only want to extract the year-month-date in the syntax it is given in, and I want to create a new column with that value as a string. Please help!

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convient way to convert int(yyyymmdd) to datetime object and str](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66038743/convient-way-to-convert-intyyyymmdd-to-datetime-object-and-str)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python datetime to string without microsecond component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999935/python-datetime-to-string-without-microsecond-component)

Comment: In general, please add data/samples as text, not image. This makes it much easier to give good answers, based on your example.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC [`pandas.Series.dt.strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) is what you want:

```
df["new_time"] = df["time"].dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

Also, check [this documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) where you can find the datetime format codes.