# to_datetime - ValueError: time data '31/03/21 00' does not match format 'dd/mm/YY HH' (match)

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have such a `time` data column in a pandas dataframe `df`:

```
'31/03/21 00'
```

`00` is the hour of a day.

I now want to get thie data to datetime-format and used this code:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], format = 'dd/mm/YY HH')
```

But get this error:

```
ValueError: time data '31/03/21 00' does not match format 'dd/mm/YY HH' (match)
```

I am now wondering how to modify the `format` option in order to get what I want?

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(df['time'], dayfirst=True)` should infer the format correctly for you.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26763344/10197418

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check https://strftime.org/ for formats:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'time' : ['31/03/21 00', '05/03/21 00']})

df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], format = '%d/%m/%y %H')

print (df)
        time
0 2021-03-31
1 2021-03-05
```