# Python how to auto pick last Trade Day closing price

Tags: python, dataframe, time-series

Hi I had created a dataframe with Acutal Close, High, Low and now I will have to calculate the Day-Change, 3Days-Change, 2weeks-Change for each of the row.
With the code below, I can see the Day-Change field with Blank/NaN value (10/27/2009 D-Chg field), and now how can I get python to Auto-Pick the last trading date (10/23/2009) AC price for calculation when shifted date doesn't exist?

```
data["D-Chg"]=stock_store['Adj Close'] - stock_store['Adj Close'].shift(1, freq='B')
```

[image]

Thanks with Regards

Comment: For me it's not really clear what you try to do, what you already have and what the problem is with what you already have...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[format your first column to datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26763344/convert-pandas-column-to-datetime).

```
data['Mycol'] =  pd.to_datetime(data['Mycol'], format='%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S.%f')
```

[get the max value](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.max.html).

```
last_date = data['date'].max()
```

Get the most up-to-date row

```
is_last = data['date'] == last_date
data[is_last]
```

This may be done in one step if you give your desired column to max().

Comment: Under "data['Mycol'] =  pd.to_datetime(data['Mycol'], format='%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S.%f')", i'm getting error - KeyError: 'Date'.
I'm currently using data['Date'] as Index.

Comment: Then you can use the Index instead of a column. df.index.max(). If you need to make your index a datetime : df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

Comment: Thanks Florian, would it be possibile to have 1 statement with if....else to check the index(date) shift1 is = 'NaN' then it will pick Max Index (Date)\Adj Close value?
    data["D-Chg"]=stock_store['Adj Close'] - if stock_store['Adj Close'].shift(1, freq='B')='NaN'......