# Pandas Date Conversion from "23-Oct-2020; 27-Aug-2020" to "10/23/2020; 8/27/2020"

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I received data from an external source that has time stamps in DDMMMYYYY format and want to convert it to MM/DD/YYYY format. Can you think of a way to do this?

Input
23-Oct-2020
27-Aug-2020
04-Dec-2019

Output that i am looking to get
10/23/2020
8/27/2020
12/04/2019

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Pandas Column to DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26763344/convert-pandas-column-to-datetime)

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
df['date'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d-%b-%Y')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. Just realized that I also have some empty rows in the data that are filled with "-" which is giving an error. Data looks like this :                                                                         
0    23-Apr-2021
1    23-Mar-2021
2              -
3    03-Dec-2020
4    04-Mar-2021
5    23-Apr-2021