# Convert Pandas column to datetime for a specific datetime format

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I would like to convert pandas column that set as a string, to datetime format. How do I convert the column?

- DataFrame Name: **df**
- Column Name: **date**
- Value format in column: **2011-06-12T01:17:56**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Pandas Column to DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26763344/convert-pandas-column-to-datetime)

Comment: Just `pd.to_datetime(df['date'])`

Comment: @user1740577 I of course looked at this one before posting this new one. It didn't help with this specific format. That's why I asked this one.

Comment: @MrFuppes I didn't know it work without a specific format. Thank you! I sure feel a little dumb now.

Comment: no worries ^^ afaik, internally, pd.to_datetime falls back to [dateutil's parser](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html), which works quite nicely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pd.to_datetime` for this.

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"date": ["2011-06-12T01:17:56"]})
```

Conversion using map method:

```py
df["date"].map(pd.to_datetime)
```

or

Conversion using apply method:

```py
df["date"].apply(pd.to_datetime)
```

or

Conversion using function on column series:

```py
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])
```

Answer (score 3):

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'].astype(str) + ' ' + df['time'].astype(str))


df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'], format= '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f')
```