# Converting string to exact date which identifies the correct year

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I have data like this:

```
+---+------+                                                                    
| id|   col|
+---+------+
|  1|210927|
|  2|210928|
|  3|210929|
|  4|210930|
|  5|211001|
+---+------+
```

I want the output like below:

```
+---+------+----------+
| id|   col|   t_date1|
+---+------+----------+
|  1|210927|27-09-2021|
|  2|210928|28-09-2021|
|  3|210929|29-09-2021|
|  4|210930|30-09-2021|
|  5|211001|01-10-2021|
+---+------+----------+
```

Which I was able to get it using `pandas` and `strptime`. Below is my code:

```
pDF= df.toPandas()
valuesList = pDF['col'].to_list()
modifiedList = list()
 
for i in valuesList:
...  modifiedList.append(datetime.strptime(i, "%y%m%d").strftime('%d-%m-%Y'))
 
pDF['t_date1']=modifiedList
 
df = spark.createDataFrame(pDF)
```

Now, the main problem is I want to `avoid` using `pandas` and `list` since I would be dealing with `millions` or even `billions` of data, and pandas slowers the process when it comes to big data.

I tried various methods in spark like `unixtime`, `to_date`, `timestamp` with the format I need but no luck, and since `strptime` only works with string I can't use it directly on column. I am not willing to create a UDF since they are slow too.

The main problem is with identifying the exact year which I wasn't able to do in spark but I am looking to implement it using spark only. What needs to be changed? Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Have you tried using vectorized method like `pd.to_datetime(df["col"].astype(str), format="%y%m%d")` instead of looping with `datetime.strptime`?

Comment: I don't want to use pandas since it doesn't work in a distributed way and I have to deal with billions of records.

Comment: https://databricks.com/blog/2021/10/04/pandas-api-on-upcoming-apache-spark-3-2.html you can use the Pandas API with Spark. I don't really understand your current code stub - you don't call a `spark` method until after you've transformed the data, so the date won't be calculated in parallel. Also you shouldn't call `to_list()` to operate on a Pandas Dataframe - map the column directly instead.

Comment: Strptime doesn't work on column directly . It has to be a string.

Comment: Yes and as @HenryYik said, that's why you need to use `pd.to_datetime()`. Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26763344/convert-pandas-column-to-datetime. You should never be moving data out of a Pandas Dataframe.

Comment: Okay so you mean if I use this method, data will be processed in parallel? Because I am talking about millions or billions of data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Python [`datetime.strptime`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/_strptime.py#L376-L383)

```py
# Open Group specification for strptime() states that a %y
#value in the range of [00, 68] is in the century 2000, while
#[69,99] is in the century 1900
if year <= 68:
    year += 2000
else:
    year += 1900
```

It's easy enough to implement this with PySpark's `when` and `otherwise`

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

(df
    .withColumn('y', F.substring('col', 0, 2).cast('int'))
    .withColumn('y', F
        .when(F.col('y') <= 68, F.col('y') + 2000)
        .otherwise(F.col('y') + 1900)
    )
    .withColumn('t_date', F.concat('y', F.regexp_replace('col', '(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})', '-$2-$3')))
    .show()
)

# Output
# +---+------+----+----------+
# | id|   col|   y|    t_date|
# +---+------+----+----------+
# |  1|210927|2021|2021-09-27|
# |  2|910927|1991|1991-09-27|
# +---+------+----+----------+
```

Technically, you can argue all day about this approach (0-68 then 69-99). But it's kind of "standard" here, so I don't see anything wrong with using it here.

Comment: How can I get it in a entire date format?

Comment: I want to retain the date as well

Comment: pls check my updated answer

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

Did you use the correct format ? Use `yyMMdd` and `to_date` for parsing, `dd-MM-yyyy` and  `date_format` for formatting should work:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
df.withColumn('t_date', f.date_format(f.to_date('col', 'yyMMdd'), 'dd-MM-yyyy')).show()

+---+------+----------+
| id|   col|    t_date|
+---+------+----------+
|  1|210927|27-09-2021|
|  2|210928|28-09-2021|
|  3|210929|29-09-2021|
|  4|210930|30-09-2021|
|  5|211001|01-10-2021|
+---+------+----------+
```

if `col` is not of string type, cast to string first:

```
df.withColumn('t_date', f.date_format(f.to_date(f.col('col').cast('string'), 'yyMMdd'), 'dd-MM-yyyy')).show()
```

Comment: If I change the value of the first record from `210927` to `920927` so I don't get the output as `27-09-1992`. Instead, I get `27-09-2092`. Using pandas I was able to get this but since it doesn't work in a distributed manner I have to avoid it.

Comment: If you prefer pandas behavior, you can use `pandas_udf` in pyspark: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.pandas_udf.html

Comment: Thanks for your help but I don't want to use UDF as well since they are slower as well.

Comment: `pandas_udf` is pretty fast based on some of the benchmark  here: https://databricks.com/blog/2017/10/30/introducing-vectorized-udfs-for-pyspark.html

Comment: But then again, you can always subtract 100 years from the date if it's in the future

Comment: How can I implement this in a dynamic manner?

Comment: Use [`when.otherwise`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.when.html#pyspark.sql.functions.when). Something like `when(year('t_date') > 2021, 't_date' - 100 years).otherwise('t_date')`

Comment: Let me try it and can you modify your answer so if it works for me then I will accept it.

Comment: It is not efficient because if my code runs next year still it will do minus 100 years which will become 1922

Comment: There are ways to get the current year. For instance, `today` from datetime module ?

Comment: Yeah this might work. Let me try it tomorrow.

Comment: I was able to subtract the year but wasn't able to retain the complete date. Please help me to retain the date. `df2 = df1.withColumn("t_date1",when(year(to_date(unix_timestamp(col('t_date'), 'dd-MM-yyyy').cast("timestamp"))) > year(current_date()), year(to_date(unix_timestamp(col("t_date"), 'dd-MM-yyyy').cast("timestamp")))-100).otherwise(col("t_date")))
`

Comment: I had to do the conversions since the column was in string and I tried my best to subtract a year from the date in spark but couldn't find any methods for this

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way:

```
(df.assign(t_date1 = pd.to_datetime('20' + df['Col'].astype(str)
                                    ,format = '%Y/%m/%d').dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')))
```

Comment: Can it be done without using pandas ?