# change timestamp format in all of rows index in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Dataframe is:

```
              A
1641171600   1353
1641171900   1370
```

should be:

```
                       A
2022-08-17 23:01:40   1353
2022-08-19 23:01:40   1370
```

I'm trying to change all row's index columns to datetime format like: `Y-m-d h:m:s`

I have tried this code:

```
df.index = df.apply(lambda x: datetime.fromtimestamp(x))
```

I saw another same question but it was about changing to upper or lower case like:

```
df.index = df.index.map(str.lower())
```

But how to apply for `datetime` instead of `str.lower()` in `map()` function !!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Pandas Column to DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26763344/convert-pandas-column-to-datetime)

Comment: I want change all row index columns @VladimirFokow

Comment: Please provide the code to reproduce your dataframe

Comment: the description is clear, I want to change all row's index column

Answer (score 0):

The code should be like this:

```
df = df.rename(index=lambda x: datetime.fromtimestamp(x))
```